# Compiling Zope2 for Android (arm-linux-androideabi-gcc LONG_BIT definition)

Tags: android, python, c++, gcc, arm

So I am trying to build zope2 for Android (ARM) using [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android), so far it had gone well however I am now hit with an error:

```
Getting distribution for 'zope.security==3.7.4'.
In file included from /home/zac/Documents/Projects/Apps/python-for-android/build/hostpython/Python-2.7.2/Include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from src/zope/security/_proxy.c:19:
/home/zac/Documents/Projects/Apps/python-for-android/build/hostpython/Python-2.7.2/Include/pyport.h:849:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
src/zope/security/_proxy.c: In function 'init_proxy':
src/zope/security/_proxy.c:1006:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   Py_INCREF(&SecurityProxyType);
   ^
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occurred when trying to install zope.security 3.7.4. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing test.
  Getting distribution for 'zope.security==3.7.4'.
Error: Couldn't install: zope.security 3.7.4
```

It seems that the issue is:

```
LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)
```